# pester test with Compare-Object fails in azure pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines, pester, compareobject

I am comparing two files which looks exactly alike, and when I test locally there is no problem, but when i run the test in my azure pipeline, the test fails and says it does not look alike.

I have no idea why or what to do for debugging?

```html
    Context "Azure Hierarchy" {
        It "Article is updated" {
            $FileContent = Get-Content $AzureHierarchyDocsFilePath
            Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $AzureHierarchy -DifferenceObject $FileContent -CaseSensitive |
            Should -BeNullOrEmpty 
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `$AzureHierarchy`? Is it actually an array of strings, similar to output of `Get-Content`?

Comment: no $AzureHierarchy it is not an array of strings, but just one string that contains all the lines

Comment: I this case I would use parameter `-Raw` for reading `$FileContent`, so it will be a single string as well and you don't need `Compare-Object` anymore. E. g. `Get-Content $AzureHierarchyDocsFilePath -Raw | Should -BeExactly $AzureHierarchy`